# rlike() function in pyspark is not working properly

Tags: regex, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, rlike

I trying to use rlike() to the money [whether it has dollar sign( $) , comma ( ,) ,  decimal sign(.) and numbers before and after the decimal sign also there can be a negative sign before / after the $ sign)
Below is the regex expression i came up with - ^$?-?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*$
its can able tp find the match, if i try to test in https://regex101.com/

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df= df.unionAll(cdf.withColumn("ErrorMessage", lit("Invalid Amount Recovered"))\
                                                           .filter(~ col("AmountRecovered").rlike('^\$?\-?[0-9]*\,?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$'))).distinct()
display(df)
```

Also i tried replacing ~ with == False like this-

```
df= df.unionAll(cdf.withColumn("ErrorMessage", lit("Invalid Amount Recovered"))\
                                                           .filter( col("AmountRecovered").rlike('^\$?\-?[0-9]*\,?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$')==False)).distinct()
```

It is not working either.

[image]

Comment: How is your regular expression not working? Are there inputs it's failing to match? If so, which inputs?

Also, you can use `\d` anywhere you use `[0-9]`. `\d` is a shortcut for a number character.

You also don't need a backslash before `-` or `,`, since those aren't special characters.

Comment: Hi @Benji, Yes the regular expression is working in the testing sites, but its not working databricks, its returning false for the valid inputs

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things wrong with your regular expression: it doesn't match a `-` before a `$` (for an input like `-$5.00`) and it doesn't let you have multiple commas (for an input like `$500,000,000,000`).

I also simplified the expression a bit by removing unnecessary `\`'s and replacing `[0-9]` with `\d`.

Here's a tweaked pattern that should match your criteria better:

`^-?\$?-?(\d*,)*\d*\.?\d*$`

You can see it in action here:
https://regexr.com/6om9n

Comment: Thank you Benji, i see the inputs are getting passed in https://regexr.com/6om9n, but in databricks its returning false , i dont know why. i added the screenshot in my questions

Comment: Can someone please help, i m stuck with pyspark saying false for my expression and Benji expression as well. attached the screenshot in my question.